Configure Turbopack to load SVGs according to resource-query
Turbopack supports loading SVGs using @svgr/webpack:
const nextConfig: NextConfig = {
  experimental: {
    turbo: {
      rules: {
        '*.svg': {
          loaders: ['@svgr/webpack'],
          as: '*.js',
        },
      },
    },
  },
}

But I want to configure it to load SVGs, in two ways, depends on the used resource-query:

Using svgr (as a React component) if imported as '.../file.svg?reat' (w/ resource-query)

Using its default loader (as StaticImageData) if imported as '.../file.svg' (w/o resource-query)



This special purpose, is feasible using Webpack:
webpack(config) {
  const defaultSvgLoader = config.module.rules.find((rule) => rule.test?.test?.('.svg'))
  config.module.rules.push(
    {
      ...defaultSvgLoader,
      test: /\.svg$/i,
      resourceQuery: {not: [...defaultSvgLoader.resourceQuery.not, /react/]}, // exclude if *.svg?react
    },
    {
      test: /\.svg$/i,
      issuer: defaultSvgLoader.issuer, // issuer: /\.[jt]sx?$/ doesn't work: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/48177#issuecomment-1506251112
      resourceQuery: /react/, // *.svg?react
      use: '@svgr/webpack',
    },
  )
  return config
}

But I want it, in Turbopack.

I did it by adding another suffix to my images. There was no other way (yet).
{
    experimental: {
        turbo: {
            rules: {
                '*.inline.svg': {
                    loaders: ['@svgr/webpack'],
                    as: '*.js',
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

